# Python inside Docker cannot print unicode without --tty

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, docker, locale

I'm trying to run a simple Python app in Docker, using the official `python:2.7` image.

My problem is that unless I enable `-t` / `--tty` in `docker run`, the python `print` command terminates when trying to print Unicode characters:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...
```

If I enable `--tty` it works without errors.

The problem is that I want to run this process in the background, using `--detach` and that mode does not support `--tty`.

What kind of changes do I need to make to my Dockerfile so that it doesn't terminate when trying to print Unicode strings?

Minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

CMD [ "python", "-c", "print (u'\\xc1')" ]
```

Minimal broken run command:

```
# error
docker run myimage 

# working
docker run --tty myimage
```

Note: it also works without problems in the official `python:3.5` image.

Comment: I've had this issue as well and am yet to find a good solution for it.

Comment: I believe I solved it with `ENV PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8` in a Dockerfile. Can you check if this fixes it?